# Basis of a finite field extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

The splitting field of $p(x)=x^4- 
x^2-3   \in\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ is $\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{3+\sqrt2} )$ because every finite field extension is normal and $\sqrt{3+\sqrt2}$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial. Now my question is how do I determine a Basis for this extension.

Comment: Naturally, consider the "infinite set" $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots\}$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$, then how would you pick a basis from this set?

Comment: @Arthur yes, but every finite field extension is normal.

Comment: @xbh is ${1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3}$ a basis?

Comment: If this $p$ is irreducible, then yeah.

Comment: Yeah. We see that $2$ is not a square in $\Bbb{F}_5$, so $\Bbb{F}_5(\sqrt2)=\Bbb{F}_{25}$. If $3+\sqrt2$ had a square root $\alpha$ in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ then, by an application of the Frobenius automorphism, $\alpha^5$ would be a square root $(3+\sqrt2)^5=3-\sqrt2$. Therefore $\alpha^6$ would be square root of $(3+\sqrt2)(3-\sqrt2)=2$. But $\alpha^6$ is in the prime field and we are back to the observation that $\sqrt2\notin\Bbb{F}_5$. Therefore $\sqrt{3+\sqrt2}$ generates a degree four extension and you are done.